# else statment not working is my syntax is incorrect on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Hi i am using if statement to change the opacity of a div on click event if a div is having the 0.5 opacity so it will change to 0 if its having 0 opacity so it will change to 0.5 i am using the following jquery code and it will change the opacity 0.5 to 0 but when i click again to change the opacity to 0 to 0.5 its not work. pls have a look on code

```
$("#one_star").click(function(){
    if($(this).css({"opacity":"0.5"}))
    {
        $(this).css({"opacity":"0"});
    }
    else if(!$(this).css({"opacity":"0.5"}))
    {
        $(this).css({"opacity":"0.5"});
    }
});
```

is i am using a wrong syntax?
any suggestion pls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression $(this).css({"opacity":"0.5"}) you have in if should return boolean **true or false** but it does not so else is not executing.

try this,

```
if($(this).css("opacity") == "0.5")
 { 
        $(this).css({"opacity":"0"});
 }
 else 
 {
     $(this).css({"opacity":"0.5"});
 }
```

Comment: so what should i use to do that so?

Comment: should use correct curly braces based on javascript good parts.

Comment: Make sure to use the triple equals `===` when doing comparisons in javascript.

Comment: If i want to use the same thing on a div with id #two_star so i have to make another function or is there any way to use this on multiple div?  like do i have to make this again
    $("#two_star").click(function(){
     if($(this).css("opacity") == "0.5")
 { 
        $(this).css({"opacity":"0"});
 }
 else 
 {
     $(this).css({"opacity":"0.5"});
 }
}

Comment: if(($('#two_star').css("opacity") == "0.5") could do the job for you

Comment: no i mean if i want to use for both #one_star and #two_star so do i haev to make different function for each?

Comment: You do not need other function you need to modify your condition in if may be something like if(($('#one_star').css("opacity") == "0.5" && ($('#two_star').css("opacity") == "0.7) or if(($('#one_star').css("opacity") == "0.5"){} else {} if(($('#two_star').css("opacity") == "0.5"){} else {} what ever suits you

Answer (score 1):

Your `if`'s are not actually checking the CSS `opacity` property.

You need to do this:

```
if ( $(this).css('opacity') == "0.5" ) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $(this).css("opacity") == "0.5") ){
        $(this).css({"opacity":"0"});
} else {
        $(this).css({"opacity":"0.5"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to check if it's not, just use the else clause:

```
$("#one_star").click(function(){
    if($(this).css("opacity") === "0.5") {
        $(this).css({"opacity":"0"});
    } else {
        $(this).css({"opacity":"0.5"});
    }
});
```